# Adding a drop-down menu (data validation) after each row of a query result in Google Sheet

Tags: validation, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

First, here is the link to my sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1067N1SAIwpGkMRBZiUv4JW8yDNkozuGt7Fwh6GW-qvE/edit#gid=1742559851

If you look at the tab called "Selection", I have two columns called "Select". All the data in these tables is collected by a query function, except column "Select". In that column, I need to add Data Validation (a simple Yes or No). I want the Data Validation to be automatically added when a new row is created but the query function instead of having to add or remove it manually every time I make some changed. Data collected by the query function is using the two variables on top of the sheet (minimum rating and global buff).

Comment: If I understand you correctly, I don't see why you can't "pre-set" the data validation for those thwo columns all the way to the bottom, to be from a List of Values, "Yes" or "No".  Then you don't need to add data validation as new data gets added to these tables.  However,.... (see next comment)

Comment: Is it possible that you have a design issue in these tables?  Your QUERY in A5 is pulling back three columns of data from sheet Jobouff.  Is it possible that this data changes - new values added to Jobouff, and since this QUERY sorts, the data can change order?  If so, the user-entered data in column D, select Yes or No, will not stay aligned with your data in cols A-C.  But if the data in Jobouff is fixed, then you shouldn't have an issue.

Comment: You are right, this is an issue. But I just started working on that project and I'm just trying out some stuff for now. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 1):

Just to show the step to apply data validation to your whole column, see the following image.  Under Cell Range, the image shows **`Selection!D5:D99`**, but this is actually set to **`Selection!D5:D999`**, it just is truncated due to the size of the text box.

Let us know if this is what you were looking for, or if I've misunderstood your issue.

[image]